Python forever while loop
I have just started programming with python and I've come across this syntax:
while True:
  do smth

and I can't seem to find a way to stop the loop
I haven't found anything that stops the loop to enable the rest of the program to function and I'd like to find something that does so

I’m voting to close this question because it can be answered by the documentation or other tutorials

if you're going to use while True, always have some if statement that can break out of the loop.

Always start with the docs: break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops

To expand on @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans comment, you can either add an if <condition>: break statement to the loop, in which case the loop will break if the condition is meti. Or use while <condition> instead (in which case the loop will break when the condition is no longer true

u can use break in while loops

As you said it is a forever loop and only stops when the while condition is False.
so this statement will never stops until you press Ctrl^C and Keyboard Interruption.
you can break a loop by break keyword inside a loop.
for example:
counter = 0
while True:
    if counter == 10:
        break
    print(counter)
    counter = counter + 1

This simple program has a while loop that prints from 0 to 9 and when counter == 10 then will break the loop.

Just declare a boolean variable and set it to true. Then do a while loop where if the variable equals True. Do the rest.
variable = True
while variable = True:
      Do something.

if you want to stop the loop, then probably write an if statement for what condition have to be met so the loop stops.
variable = True
while variable = True:
      Do something.
      if a = b:
         variable = False

the a = b is really generic, its more a placeholder where you put your condition down.

If you're going to include pseudocode in your answer, at least mark it clearly. if the condition is met is not actually valid Python, but it's close enough that some folks might get confused.
